# R Programing, Read in and Run multiple files

Tags: r, genetics

I'm using a program called [COLONY](http://www.zsl.org/science/research-projects/software/colony,1154,AR.html) from some genetic analysis.  Colony has an R package ([rcolony](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rcolony/)).

What I need to do is move text files from a directory ("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles") into another directory ("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/") rename it "Colony2.dat", run colony, then when finished repeat the process for all files in the original directory.

This is what we've been able to come up with so far. The issue is that it seems to be trying to run every text file at the same time rather than cycling through them.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/")
getwd()
datFiles <- list.files("datFiles")
library(rcolony)

for (dat in datFiles)
{
  setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles")
  file.rename(dat,"Colony2.DAT")
  file.copy(from = "C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles/Colony2.DAT",to = "C:/GenSoftware/Colony/")
  datPath <- "C:/GenSoftware/Colony/Colony2.DAT"
  setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/")
  run.colony(colonyexecpath = "Colony2.exe", datPath, wait = FALSE, monitor = TRUE)
  setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles/")
  file.rename("Colony2.DAT",dat)
}
```

Comment: What you have written looks fine. It definitely isn't trying to run them at the same time. Can you post some more information about what is happening when you run it?

Comment: Yes, you appear to be correct. It is running three instances of colony though.  I'm not sure if the instances are analyzing the same file three times or if it is somehow parsing it out.  I just acquired a couple more computer to run things on and there may have been some version incompatibility occurring because it now seems to be running just one instance.

Here is a screenshot of what was occurring last night when it was running two instances: http://i.imgur.com/u3BnMQ7.png  Thanks taking the time to help me.

Comment: This is the current state of things http://i.imgur.com/GT3OPhU.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles")
listofFile = list.files()
Records <- as.data.frame(listofFile)
count <- nrow(Records)
x = 1:count

for(i in seq(along=x))
{
  file.rename(listofFile[i],"Colony2.DAT")
  file.copy(from = "C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles/Colony2.DAT",to = "C:/GenSoftware/Colony/")
  datPath <- "C:/GenSoftware/Colony/Colony2.DAT"
  setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/")
  run.colony(colonyexecpath = "Colony2.exe", datPath, wait = FALSE, monitor = TRUE)
  setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles/")
  file.rename("Colony2.DAT",dat)
}
```

sorry didn't have time to test because I'm running some intensive stuff on my machine.

This will definitely show you it the process iterate through the directory of files

```
setwd("C:/GenSoftware/Colony/datFiles")
listofFile = list.files()
Records <- as.data.frame(listofFile)
count <- nrow(Records)
x = 1:count

for(i in seq(along=x))
{
  print(listofFile[i])
}
```

Comment: Is it posible to use the same code to read a file with the same name but allocated in a different folders in a directory? I don't know how to make that in R because in others software is to slow!

Comment: Do you mean search for file name in different directories?

Comment: example: We want to process file TotalSodaSales.txt and the file is the following directories: c:\sodasales\2011, c:\sodasales\2012, c:\sodasales\2013, c:\sodasales\2014

Comment: Yes, Exactly you said but in my case I have excel files but I am in trouble with that reading of files!

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm slow in replying.     

The original problem may not have been running all three files at the same time but opening three instances of COLONY.  I'm not sure if it was running the same file three times, or some way parsing the project somehow.    

I ran your code this morning and a similar thing happened.  Three instances of colony started running. However, I just got your code onto a newer computer at work and now only one instance is running.  I'm going to let it run to completion and see what happens.  I'll let you know the results.    

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Please If you know how to read the same file from different directories I would thank you @user2600629

Comment: I would if I could: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"